# Pass Filtered Table data to ListBox

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table below:

[image]

I'm trying to filter the data and then display the filtered data to a Listbox on a userform.
Code so far:

```
Dim iList As Variant

Sheet1.ListObjects("PostOneTable").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=TextBox1.Value & "*"
Sheet1.ListObjects("PostOneTable").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=TextBox2.Value & "*"
Sheet1.ListObjects("PostOneTable").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=TextBox3.Value & "*"
Sheet1.ListObjects("PostOneTable").Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=TextBox4.Value & "*"

Dim jList As Range

Set jList = 
Sheet1.ListObjects("PostOneTable").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

ListBox1.List = jList
```

However, upon running the code, I run into a few problems.
Firstly, the filters don't seem to apply correctly. For example, if I use a string, such as:

```
Sheet1.ListObjects("PostOneTable").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="ryd"
```

I would expect to only see the fourth item, both in the Table and in the ListBox. However, both are blank.

Second issue is that the code doesn't drive the filtered list to the textbox.

Please note that I am aware of other ways to search, using loops. However, this method
is good because the end users will be able to see results of their actions on the form directly in the table.

Thanks!

EDIT:
Upon playing with it, I noticed something interesting. If I comment out the section that drives the data to the listbox AND rewrite the filtering lines, the filtering now works.

Comment: The ListBox must be formatted to have as many columns as the List that you assign to it. You should also specify the widths for all columns and assign a BoundColumn.

Comment: @Variatus all done. Listbox has six columns and widths are properly specified. This was all done in property box; not in code

Comment: In that case try assigning the unfiltered DataBodyRange to the listbox. If that works transfer `jList.Value` to an array formatted by your code. If it doesn't work transfer `jList.Value` to a string array. But either way would take as much code and time as using the Add method to populate the listbox :-)

Comment: @Variatus the error code is "Could not set the List property. Invalid property array index." error is on "ListBox1.List = jList". Can you show me the Add method? Since posting, I might be more of a fan of a loop...

Comment: The `AddItem` method is a bit of a pain for multiple columns of data and a lot slower that assigning an array to the `ListBox.List`. But it is probably easier for my answer for a beginner or intermediate developer to write then my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Range.Value` only returns the values from the first area in a range. `Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` will return a Range that has an Area for each contiguous block of cells.

> ```
> ListBox1.List = jList
> ```

`ListBox1.List` will only have the data for the first group of visible rows (the first Are in `jList`).

You can still use the `ListObject` to filter the data.  You just need to write a function to return the visible data.  Which is a trivia task to do.

> ListBox1.List = ListObjectVisibleData(Sheet1.ListObjects("PostOneTable"))

```
Public Function ListObjectVisibleData(ByVal ListObject As ListObject)
    Dim Map As New Collection
    Dim Row As Range
    For Each Row In ListObject.DataBodyRange.Rows
        If Not Row.EntireRow.Hidden Then
            Map.Add Row
        End If
    Next
    
    Dim Results As Variant
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    
    If Map.Count = 0 Then
        ReDim Results(1 To 1, 1 To ListObject.ListColumns.Count)
    Else
        ReDim Results(1 To Map.Count, 1 To ListObject.ListColumns.Count)
        For Each Row In Map
            r = r + 1
            For c = 1 To UBound(Results, 2)
                Results(r, c) = Row.Cells(1, c).Value
            Next
        Next
    End If
    
    ListObjectVisibleData = Results
End Function
```

Comment: Wow. Like a charm. I am curious about something. What is "ReDim"? I haven't seen much, but I definitely never seen that. Granted this isn't a tutoring session...

Comment: `ReDim` is short for `Redimension`.  It allow you to set the dimensions of an array. You should type Redim into a code module and press F1 to navigate to the help documentation.